# User orderr status lookup in Wordpress WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Using WooCommerce, is there a way for the user to lookup their order status?
Seems like a straightforward thing, but I don't know if it was built into the system.

Thanks.

Comment: its in the my-account page.

Comment: [woocommerce_order_tracking] – shows the order tracking form

Comment: Can a guest user lookup their order by order ID?

Comment: I just tried it using [woocommerce_order_tracking]  and it works great. Thanks!